# Show that $\int_0^af(x)\,dx + \int_0^bf^{-1}(x)\,dx \geq ab\; \forall a,b \in \mathbb{R}^+.$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, definite-integrals, integral-inequality

Let $f: [0,\infty) \rightarrow [0,\infty)$ be an onto, strictly increasing function. This problem looks like $\textbf{Young's Inequality}$ but it does not say that $f(0)=0$ or does the fact that I am told that the function is strictly increasing imply that $f(0)=0$.

That is the doubt I have with this problem. Thank you very much in advance to anyone that can help me clear that doubt!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f(0) = 0$ is implied by the conditions: Assume that $f(0) = b >0$. Then 
$f([0, \infty)) \subset [b, \infty) $ because $f$ is increasing. On the other hand, $0 \in f([0, \infty))$ because $f$ maps *onto* $[0, \infty)$.

Or shorter:
$$
 0 \le f(0) \le  f(f^{-1}(0)) = 0 \implies f(0) = 0 \, .
$$

So you can apply Young's inequality. For a proof see [Proof of Young's inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1132153/proof-of-youngs-inequality) or [Prove that for $a,b > 0$, we have $\int_{0}^a f(x)dx+\int_{0}^b f^{-1}(x)dx \geq ab$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1753542/prove-that-for-a-b-0-we-have-int-0a-fxdx-int-0b-f-1xdx-geq).

Comment: Thank you very much for clearing that up and for the links!